# Edittext not visible

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

In my application I have 3 buttons and one listView and one editText with image.
My problem is that when I am editing task in my editText the size of the editText is reduced very much.This problem occurs only on mobile. Please help me.
[image]
This is my layout file:

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="10" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="30" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/todaytaskbtnid"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="10"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonselector"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="TODAY" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/tomorrowtaskbtnid"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="10"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonselector"
            android:text="TOMORROW" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/futuretaskbtnid"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="10"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonselector"
            android:text="FUTURE" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="8" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/frontpagetasklistid"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edittextidAddTodayTask"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/edittextselector"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/addtask"
            android:hint="Add Today Task"
            android:lines="3"
            android:maxLines="5"
            android:minLines="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Mobile shot:
[image]

Comment: Could you post a screenshot?

Comment: wait i will be posted

Comment: i send screen shot pl give solution

Comment: Size seems fine to me!

Comment: when i am run mobile the edittext visibility much lessar because the keyboard take a place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you shouldn't use layout weights in this situtation or you've mixed them.
You can leave the linear layouts with the weights for the rows, but since you want the edit text to appear at the bottom of the screen, what I would do is wrap everything in a RelativeLayout, then draw the edit text and align it to the parent's bottom and then put the linear layout aligned to be above the edit text.

Try this layout (and of course, don't forget to change the drawables to your drawables since I removed some of them):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
     >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edittextidAddTodayTask"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/addtask"
            android:hint="Add Today Task"
            android:lines="3"
            android:maxLines="5"
            android:minLines="1" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/topButtons"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:weightSum="30" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/todaytaskbtnid"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="10"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="TODAY" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/tomorrowtaskbtnid"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="10"
            android:text="TOMORROW" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/futuretaskbtnid"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="10"
            android:text="FUTURE" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/edittextidAddTodayTask"
        android:layout_below="@id/topButtons"
         >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/frontpagetasklistid"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: which is fine but the list item visible under the buttons i already use this manner but getting this problem...

Comment: Did you test it...? Are you sure you've set the layout above and layout below for the listview's LinearLayout?

Answer (score 0):

try giving EditText's `android:layout_height="0dp"`

Answer (score 0):

What about reducing weigght for the listview while increasing weight for the edit text linear layout?This will enhance the size of your edit text.I Dont think your xml code for your edit text needs any weight because it fills parent layout.

Answer (score -1):

You need to make sure your `<activity>` tag in AndroidManifest.xml does not have a configChanges attribute like this :
`android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation"`

This will redraw activity when keyboard is shown or orientation changes.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config

Comment: Surely the fragment is hosted inside an activity .. it can't exist on its own :)

Comment: -1 for recommending a hack to a beginner who is unlikely to understand why it's so bad.

Comment: @Satheesh can you send device screenshot .. you can take it in DDMS .. you'll see a camera icon in the devices panel

Comment: Hmm .. I see your problem .. I suggest you include the configChanges line in your manifest and in onConfigurationChanged() hide the middle LinearLayout that contains the ListView. When the user clicks the plus button you can show it again.